# Mostrar solo un elemento de body HTML y javascript

Tags: javascript, html

El motivo de mi pregunta es como es posible mostrar solamente un elemento de body con javascript. Se que para ocultar un elemento es posible con:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName')[0].style.display='none'
```

¿Cómo es posible en vez de ir ocultando todos los elementos mostrar solamente uno?

Saludos.

Comment: Tenemos muchos contenedores en el documento html, yo solo quiero mostrar uno de ellos y ocultar los demás. En vez de ir ocultando con el código que escribí todos, quizás halla una forma de mostrar solo uno. con display block muestra todos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es muy amplia y puede abordarse de diferente manera, para que utilizar **Javascript** cuando eso lo puedes realizar con **CSS** te muestro un ejemplo:

1.- Tenemos un `div` con la clase `contenedores` y dentro hay varios **contenedores**

```
<div class="contenedores">
    <div class="contenedor1">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 1
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor2">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 2
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor3">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 3
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor4">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 4
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor5">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 5
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor5">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 5
    </div>
  </div>
```

2.- Con **CSS** ocultamos todos de la siguiente manera:

```
.contenedores > div {
  display: none;
}
```

3.- Estamos diciendo que todos los `divs` que hay dentro del elemento con la clase `contenedores` se oculten

4.- Ahora solo puedes mostrar el que tu desees de la siguiente manera:

```
.contenedores :nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

5.- Estamos diciendo que el **"hijo"** numero 2 del elemento `contenedores` se mostrará.

**Ejemplo practico de lo anterior planteado:**

```css
.contenedores > div {
  display: none;
}

.contenedores :nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedores">
    <div class="contenedor1">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 1
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor2">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 2
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor3">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 3
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor4">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 4
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor5">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 5
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor5">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 5
    </div>
  </div>
```

6.- **Si lo deseas realizar con **JavaScript**

```
// ACCEDEMOS A TODOS LOS CONTENEDORES

let contenedores = document.querySelectorAll(".contenedores>div");

// querySelectorAll NOS DEVUELVE UNA LISTA DE NODOS DE TODOS ESOS CONTENEDORES

// RECORREMOS ESA LISTA Y OCULTAMOS TODOS LOS CONTENEDORES

contenedores.forEach((contenedor) => {
  contenedor.style.display = "none";
});

//AHORA SOLO MOSTRAMOS EL CONTENEDOR DESEADO

document.querySelector(".contenedores :nth-child(2)").style.display = "block";
```

7.- Ejemplo practico con lo anterior planteado:

```js
// ACCEDEMOS A TODOS LOS CONTENEDORES

let contenedores = document.querySelectorAll(".contenedores>div");

// querySelectorAll NOS DEVUELVE UNA LISTA DE NODOS DE TODOS ESOS CONTENEDORES

// RECORREMOS ESA LISTA Y OCULTAMOS TODOS LOS CONTENEDORES

contenedores.forEach((contenedor) => {
  contenedor.style.display = "none";
});

//AHORA SOLO MOSTRAMOS EL CONTENEDOR DESEADO

document.querySelector(".contenedores :nth-child(2)").style.display = "block";
```

```html
<div class="contenedores">
    <div class="contenedor1">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 1
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor2">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 2
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor3">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 3
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor4">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 4
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor5">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 5
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor5">
      SOY EL CONTENEDOR 5
    </div>
  </div>
```

**NOTA: TE DEJO UNOS ENLACES QUE PODRIAN INTERESARTE:**

[Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

[Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas recorrerlos todos, basta con que estén ocultos desde el inicio, excepto uno; dentro de una función ocultas el que esté visible y muestras el seleccionado.

En esta propuesta incluí dos opciones:

1. Por *select*, donde envías el índice del elemento a mostrar
2. Por botón, donde se muestra uno por uno en cada clic

```js
// Obtener todos los elementos a mostrar / ocultar
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.clase');
// Cuál se debe mostrar
let activo = 0;

// Llenar div con opciones
let sel = document.querySelector('#selactivo');
divs.forEach(div => {
    let opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.text = div.innerText;
    sel.add(opt);
});

// Definir función para ocultar activo y mostrar seleccionado
function cambiar(mostrar) {
    // Primero ocultar el que está activo
    divs[activo].style.display = 'none';
    // Mostrar el que se proporcionó por parámetro
    divs[mostrar].style.display = 'block';
    // Actualizar variable para marcar activo
    activo = mostrar;
}

// Mostrar por select, enviando índice
sel.addEventListener('change', e => cambiar(sel.selectedIndex));

// Ciclo con botón
document.querySelector('#siguiente').addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Incrementar
    mostrar = activo + 1;
    // Si es después del último, volver al inicio
    if(mostrar == divs.length) {
        mostrar = 0;
    }
    // Mostrar el que corresponde
    cambiar(mostrar);
    // Actualizar select
    sel.value = divs[activo].innerText;
});
```

```css
.clase { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="clase" style="display:block;">Div 1</div>
<div class="clase">Div 2</div>
<div class="clase">Div 3</div>
<div class="clase">Div 4</div>
Selecciona: <select id="selactivo"></select><br>
<button id="siguiente">Mostrar siguiente</button>
```